Manhwa where the blonde, stoic female lead reincarnates/regresses into a kid and has a brother. Together they are friends with a black-haired kid
The female lead (FL) is known to be emotionless and can wield a sword really well. I remember a scene where the three (the FL, brother, and black-haired friend) heard rumors of a ghost in their castle and they tried to investigate. The FL wasn't scared but the other two were. Their dynamic seemed to be like that; the boys being idiots and roping her along with them (wholesome, cute and funny, lmao).
I think that the black-haired friend is also a noble/royal who visits the FL and brother's family over summers???
I think there was also a scene where the FL gets kidnapped and she shows off her sword and survival skills (like from before she regressed/reincarnated); it was bloody or something.
There wasn't really any romance that I could remember -- it was just a really good friendship between the three.
I will greatly appreciate it if anyone knows the name of this manhwa. Thank you so much! :D <3

This is The Duke's Bored Daughter is My Master.

I was an illegitimate daughter abandoned by the promiscuous emperor. From there, I ended up on the street where I learned that I had a knack for the sword. I competed in tournaments, became a mercenary, and I made a name for myself. Just when I had become the talk of the empire, the emperor wanted me back. In return, I demanded to be next in line for the throne. After years of hard work, I finally became empress and died happily. But here I am, alive again. Ugh, can’t a girl be left alone? This time, I’m going to be as lazy as I please!

In her first life, the protagonist was Dante Lenatus, the illegitimate daughter of a crown prince. After being abandoned by her parents and left to fend for herself, she was adopted by the instructor of a swordsmanship academy and grew up to become a famous swordswoman, and later an empress.
She died at the age of 33 and was reincarnated 500 years later as Helena Ferresca, the silver-haired, 10-year-old daughter of a duke. She retains her memories and swordsmanship skills from her previous life, and has a silver-haired, 13-year-old brother named Leonard. However, she initially suffers from apathy, finding her new life uninteresting, until she comes up with the idea of teaching Leonard swordsmanship.
In chapter 4, Prince Caesar, who has black hair and is similar in age to Helena and Leonard, comes to stay at their estate for the summer. His visits become an annual event each summer.
In chapter 8, the three children are told about a ghost known as the Lady in the Blue Dress, who supposedly appears in the cellar on rainy, summer nights. The boys are both scared by the prospect of the ghost, while Helena isn't, but all three sneak down to the cellar to see it for themselves.



In chapter 10, Caesar is kidnapped by three men and Helena rescues him, using a broken chair leg to beat the men unconscious and getting blood on her face and dress in the process.



You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.

THIS IS IT THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU BEAUTIFUL HUMAN BLESSINGS BE UPON YOU MAY U HAVE THE JUICIEST MEAL FOR DINNER AND THE COZIEST BED FOR LATE NIGHT READING :'DDDDD
